# Android Updating Stripte Terminal returns UNEXPECTED_SDK_ERROR

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I have an Android App that connects to a stripe terminal using the Stripe Terminal External SDK version `2.14.0`; on Android 13, we are getting `UNEXPECTED_SDK_ERROR` error code in the `OnFinishInstallingUpdate` method when updating the terminal firmware, the terminal isn't the problem because we were able to update it using our iOS app.

Has someone experienced this problem before with `Android 13` and Stripe Terminal External SDK version `2.14.0`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the SDK to a newer version (the latest one is [2.19.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-terminal-android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2190---2023-04-03)) and see if it solves the problem.